# How can I copy a header from parent exchange to child exchange after calling split?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have below code.The fireTime header is available before the split , I want to use it after the call of split as well which is not available as per logs. Camel version in pom is 2.17.3.
Both code and logs are as below.

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception 
    {
        LOGGER.debug("Configuring client for UnicomOrderReader::synchInventoryAndOrders");

        from("quartz2://timer1?cron=0 0 * ? * * *")
            .log(" Unicom Job fired at ${header.fireTime}")
                .process(activeInitializedClientTaskProcessor)
                    .split(simple("${body}"))
                        .log("After Split Unicom Job fired at ${header.fireTime}")
                            .to("activemq:queue:" + ActiveMQNames.UNICOM_INVENTORY_ORDER_READER_QUEUE)
                                .log("Executed route to sync inventory and orders from Unicom ");
    }
```

logs output as below:-

```
oms-04 Jun 2019 12:00:00,048 INFO DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1 [route42] -  Unicom Job fired at Tue Jun 04 12:00:00 IST 2019
oms-04 Jun 2019 12:00:00,280 INFO DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1 [route42] - After Split Unicom Job fired at
oms-04 Jun 2019 12:00:00,298 INFO DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1 [route42] - After Split Unicom Job fired at
oms-04 Jun 2019 12:00:00,312 INFO DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1 [route42] - After Split Unicom Job fired at
oms-04 Jun 2019 12:00:00,317 INFO DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1 [route42] - After Split Unicom Job fired at
oms-04 Jun 2019 12:00:00,322 INFO DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1 [route42] - After Split Unicom Job fired at
oms-04 Jun 2019 12:00:00,327 INFO DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1 [route42] - After Split Unicom Job fired at
oms-04 Jun 2019 12:00:00,332 INFO DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1 [route42] - After Split Unicom Job fired at
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store variables in the properties and make use of them later in the chain, see the `.setProperty("myHeader", header("theheadername"))` below:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception 
{
    LOGGER.debug("Configuring client for UnicomOrderReader::synchInventoryAndOrders");

    from("quartz2://timer1?cron=0 0 * ? * * *")
        .log(" Unicom Job fired at ${header.fireTime}")
            .process(activeInitializedClientTaskProcessor)
            .setProperty("myHeader", header("theheadername"))
                .split(simple("${body}"))
//here you can access ${property.myHeader} for example by passing it as an argument to a bean method
                    .bean(myBean, "myMethod(${property.myHeader}, ${Body})")
                    .log("After Split Unicom Job fired at ${header.fireTime}")
                        .to("activemq:queue:" + ActiveMQNames.UNICOM_INVENTORY_ORDER_READER_QUEUE)
                            .log("Executed route to sync inventory and orders from Unicom ");
}
```